# How to install tensorflow on Mac?

Tags: tensorflow

I used `pip install` to install tensorflow on my mac. It shows like that: `Successfully installed numpy-1.14.5 setuptools-39.2.0 tensorboard-1.10.0 tensorflow-1.10.1`.
But when I open python, and try to `import tensorflow`, it occurs an error.

[image]

I don't know what happened.
I tried to use `sudo pip3 install --upgrade tfBinaryURL` but it still has the same problem. I delete the folder of tensorflow, and installed it again, but the error still exists.

Comment: Did you go to the link at the end of the stack trace? What did you try, and what did not work?

Comment: In the first statement, you are trying `sudo pip install tensorflow`. In the other, you are doing `sudo pip3 ...`. I am assuming that you installed Tensorflow for Python2, and are trying to import it in Python3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its a conflict between TensorFlow1.10 and your Mac OS version. Check this answer: [Installing Tensorflow 1.10 on El Capitan 10.11.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848122/installing-tensorflow-1-10-on-el-capitan-10-11-6/51925618#51925618)

Answer (score 0):

For me, this fixed the problem: `python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl`